# ¿Cómo sumar mis campos en django?

Tags: python, django

Tengo una base de datos y me gustaría sumar los campos de manera vertical y horizontal, y que se muestren en una tabla, algo como la que tengo aquí[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me gustaría que en lugar del signo de $, aparezca la suma solo de los meses, se que se usa un model.objects.aggregate(suma('campo')) , pero no se como usarlo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]. Es importante que indiques que has intentado y añadas el código para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte. Un saludo

Comment: proporciona código, no imágenes

Comment: Hola, podrías postear el código de tu(s) modelo(s) para poder tener una mejor idea de lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Deduzco que tienes un modelo del siguiente estilo:

```
from django.db import models


class MiModelo(models.Model):
    capitulo = models.IntegerField()
    enero = models.FloatField()
    # ...
    diciembre = models.FloatField()
```

En caso ser correcto el modelo puedes hacer dos consultas, una para obtener cada fila, agregando el total de la filtra, y otra consulta para obtener los totales por columna.

Consulta por filas agregando el total:

```
from django.db import Sum
MiModelo.objects.annotate(total=Sum('enero') + ... + Sum('diciembre'))
```

Consulta de totales por columnas:

```
MiModelo.objects.aggregate(total_enero=Sum('enero'), ..., total_diciembre=Sum('diciembre'))
```

Para profundizar en los `annotate` y `aggregate` te recomiendo ver la siguiente página de la documentación:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/